# Module 'secp256k1-browserify' not found on using browserify with ethereumjs-lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, ethereum

I am trying to run a simple script in browser using the `ethereumjs-lib` library installed. I use `browserify` to generate the required javascript file to embed into the html page, but it is giving me an error regarding missing module `secp256k1-browserify` as follows:

```
Cannot find module 'secp256k1-browserify' from '/home/user/node_modules/ethereumjs-lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/lib/precompiled'
```

Anyone familiar with `ethereum` or `ethereumjs-lib` please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Do you have the [secp256k1-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secp256k1-browserify) package installed?

Comment: No, I installed it using `npm install secp256k1-browserify` but now I am facing issue of missing `sha3` module, even though I have it installed already.

Answer (score 0):

secp256k1-browserify was deprecated. Please use the latest (2.0.0) ethereumjs-lib version.